# JFormattedTextField unusual format

Tags: java, swing, formatting, jformattedtextfield, swing-highlighter

I am formatting a text field like this:

```
bidField = new JFormattedTextField();
DecimalFormat d = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
int dp = 5;
d.setMinimumFractionDigits(dp);

NumberFormatter dnff = new NumberFormatter(d);
DefaultFormatterFactory factory = new DefaultFormatterFactory(dnff);
bidField.setFormatterFactory(factory);
```

But I would like to make part or last 2 digits BOld or diff color a bit like:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: NOT POSSIBLE . correct me if i am wrong :) solution would be to use multiple labels and split up the text

Comment: I think it might be. The above is from java and I managed to change the number of pips displayed. I don't think I could have done that if it was multiple fields.

Comment: +1 for question, maYBe but I don't know how to do it without using a Html

Comment: the reason i said its **not possible** is **Because** you can format the whole jtextfield but **partial** one has no predefined methods to use .. **maybe creating CustomJTextfield extending jtextfield will help**